# FATAL EXCEPTION OkHttp Dispatcher java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

[image: logcat]

When my app launches and I go to login/signup screen. When I enter the data and clicks button, where the authentication (login/signup) API is called, The app crashes with a toast of Network error and the error in logcat is shown in the screenshot above.

My code for `okhttpclient`:

```
private fun getRetrofitClient(): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().also {
                it.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                it.addHeader(
                    "Authorization",
                    "Bearer ${Paper.book().read<UserResponse>("APIresponse")?.token}"
                )
            }.build())
        }.also { client ->
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            client.addInterceptor(logging)
            client.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            client.readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }.build()
}
```

the other code in my app fro API call etc:

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/signUp")
fun createUser(
    @Field("name") name: String,
    @Field("email") email: String,
    @Field("password") password: String,
    @Field("loginWith") loginWith: String,
    @Field("fcm_token") fcmToken: String,
    @Field("device_type") deviceType: String,
): Call<UserResponse>


@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/login")
fun loginUser(
    @Field("email") email: String,
    @Field("password") password: String,
    @Field("loginWith") loginWith: String,
    @Field("fcm_token") fcmToken: String,
    @Field("device_type") deviceType: String
): Call<UserResponse>
```

The API's call in Activities:

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserResponse>, response: Response<UserResponse>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val userResponse: UserResponse? = response.body()

            if (userResponse?.status == true) {
                val user: LoginUser? = userResponse.user
                if (user != null) {
                    Paper.book().write("APIresponse", userResponse)
                    showToast("Signup Successful for user: ${user.name}")
                    navigateToMainActivity()
                } else {
                    showToast("User information not available")
                }
            } else {
                // Signup failed with a message in userResponse.message
                showToast("Signup Failed: ${userResponse?.message}")
            }
        } else {
            // Handle non-successful response, e.g., HTTP error codes
            handleErrorResponse(response)
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        showToast("Network Error. Please check your internet connection.")
    }

})
```

In `LoginActivity`:

```
val call: Call<UserResponse> = apiService.loginUser(enteredEmail, enteredPassword, loginWith, fcm_token, device_type)

call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserResponse>, response: Response<UserResponse>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            loginButton.isEnabled = true
            val userResponse: UserResponse? = response.body()

            if (userResponse?.status == true) {
                val loginUser: LoginUser? = userResponse.user
                if (loginUser != null) {
                    showToast("Login Successful for user: ${loginUser.name}")

                    Paper.book().write("APIresponse", userResponse)
                    val loggedInUserResponse: UserResponse? = Paper.book().read("APIresponse")
                    val token: String? = loggedInUserResponse?.token
                    Log.d("UserProfile", "Logged In User: $token")
                    navigateToMainActivity()
                } else {
                    showToast("User information not available")
                }
            } else {
                showToast("Login Failed: ${userResponse?.message}")
                Log.e("LoginActivity", "Login Failed: ${userResponse?.message}")
            }
        } else {
            handleErrorResponse(response)
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        Log.d("LoginApiError",t.toString())
        showToast("Network Error. Please check your internet connection.")
        loginButton.isEnabled = true
    }
})
```

The DataClasses are:

```
 data class LoginUser(
    val id: Int?,
    val name: String?,
    val username: String?,
    val email: String?,
    val bio: String?,
    @SerializedName("fcm_token") val fcmToken: String?,
    @SerializedName("device_type") val deviceType: String?,
    @SerializedName("login_with") val loginWith: Any?,
    @SerializedName("profile_picture") val profilePicture: String?,
    @SerializedName("cover_picture") val coverPicture: String?,
    val address: String?,
    val status: Int?,
    @SerializedName("email_verified_at") val emailVerifiedAt: Any?,
    @SerializedName("created_at") val createdAt: String?,
    @SerializedName("updated_at") val updatedAt: String?,
    val posts: List<LogUserPost>?,
    val follower: List<Follower>?,
    val following: List<Following>?,
    val likes: List<UserLikes>?
  )

data class UserResponse(
    val status: Boolean,
    val user: LoginUser,
    val token: String,
    val message: String
)

data class LogUserPost(
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("user_id") val userId: Int,
    @SerializedName("category_id") val categoryId: Int,
    @SerializedName("compare_with") val compareWith: Any?,
    val media: String,
    val title: String,
    val body: String,
    @SerializedName("media_type") val mediaType: String,
    val download: Int,
    @SerializedName("created_at") val createdAt: String,
    @SerializedName("updated_at") val updatedAt: String,
    val likes: List<UserLikes>?
)

data class Follower(
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("following_user_id") val followingUserId: Int,
    @SerializedName("followed_user_id") val followedUserId: Int,
    @SerializedName("created_at") val createdAt: String,
    @SerializedName("updated_at") val updatedAt: String
)

data class Following(
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("following_user_id") val followingUserId: Int,
    @SerializedName("followed_user_id") val followedUserId: Int,
    @SerializedName("created_at") val createdAt: String,
    @SerializedName("updated_at") val updatedAt: String
)

data class UserLikes(
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("post_id") val postId: Int,
    @SerializedName("user_id") val userId: Int,
    @SerializedName("comment_id") val commentId: Any?,
    @SerializedName("category_id") val categoryId: Any?,
    @SerializedName("created_at") val createdAt: String,
    @SerializedName("updated_at") val updatedAt: String
)
```